# SQL command to get highscore position with similar scores

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please guide me to write an optimize sql command to get real position(ranking) of the users by id order with similar scores.

I have written below Select Command but it can't distinguish names with **similar scores** and if i use "AND" to specify the gamer's name it only shows number 1 as row number that is not what i want !

*Fields : id , name , score*

```
SELECT        COUNT(id) AS Num
FROM            Hscore
WHERE        (score>= @scorenumber)
```

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I believe you are looking for group by Id or group by Name

Comment: It is Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: What do you mean by "similar".  is this supposed to be exact same, or just close to the original number?

Comment: When i group it all rows with same value place to a row . For example if have 4 records of score 100 i don't know what should i do ! i know i can use a loop to count and comparison the values in c# but i think it's not optimized !

Comment: Gene , exactly the same .

Comment: Please provide some sample data (SQL Fiddle maybe)

Comment: And expected result would be helpful too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    [RANK]
    , ID
    , NAME
    , SCORE
FROM (
    SELECT
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) [RANK]
        , ID
        , NAME
        , SCORE
    FROM Hscore
    WHERE (score>=@scorenumber)
) ResultSet
WHERE Name = 'Milad'
ORDER BY SCORE DESC
```

I'm assuming you're using SQL Server, since you're using the standard notation for a variable, with a @ before the variable name.

Comment: No my friend i know this solution.I want to filter the names too. for example : WHERE (score>=@scorenumber) AND Name='Radu'

Comment: @MiladHatam So? Add the `Name` filter as well.

Comment: And it gives me 1 row and i get number 1 ! I want to get the position of the users in table by their scores! Imagine you write a highscore game and want to show the gamers their positions ( New gamers with higher id have to catch the top positions with the same scores) ! If the scores was not the same my solution and your solution exactly was ok .

Comment: @MiladHatam Have you tested my solution? If so, give some sample data for testing and the expected result.

Comment: Yes i've tested it my friend and it returns 2*X that i tested it before .my solution only returns 1 result and it was the number of the filtered records.

Comment: @MiladHatam How about this version?

Comment: Thank you man.I Think in this case Row_Number() is better but my problem is that i want to filter gamer names too, to find out their exact positions.I had better select all rows>@score and make comparison by c# in this case!

Comment: @MiladHatam This new version of my code should do just that, show an actual ranking for users, with an uninterrupted range (1, 1, 2, 3 if two players have the same score that's at the top). You can still add the `Name` filter at this point.

Comment: Yes ... It works like a charm! ;) Thank you man ... This multiple select makes magic. I only forced to change this line of code : DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) [RANK].I will put your name in Special Thanks section. ;) Thanks again

Comment: @MiladHatam Haha, you're welcome. Give me a link when the game is over.

Comment: https://cafebazaar.ir/app/air.CyrusX86/?l=en       Here it is my friend ;) Find your name in About section ;) Thanks again ...